# How should I specify an item in a checkbox list, when using the dom?

Tags: wordpress, vba, ms-access, dom, checkbox

I am currently automating use of the wordpress editor using VBA in access 2003, but would like to extend the automation to include the selection of category, taxonomy items etc.
That is with Checkbox lists.
An example with the same structure is here: http://devblog.xing.com/frontend/the-checkbox-list/

My list is based on a hierarchy of geographic entities: On the local database I may have data associated with the locality: Algeria for instance.
I want to be able to use (ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer) ie.document.what?

I am a bit lost as to an elegant approach. I haven't tried it yet but I guess I can get the innerhtml for each selectit class, check to see if it contains my keyword an if so extract the input id with a bit of string manipulation, and then use ie.document.getelementbyid("whatever").Click Check or Toggle

But is there a better approach?

(Ultimately I will have to look at how to connect to the remote database and drag the tag_id from the tables there - but I thought this would be quicker especially in that the automation functionality in a larger sense already exists)

Any pointers appreciated!

```
<ul id="localitieschecklist" class="categorychecklist form-no-clear"
data-wp-lists="list:localities">
<li id="localities-8" class="popular-category">
<label class="selectit">
<input id="in-localities-8" type="checkbox" name="tax_input[localities][]" value="8"> </input>
Africa
</label>
<ul class="children"><li id="localities-96">
<label class="selectit"><input id="in-localities-96" type="checkbox" name="tax_input[localities][]" value="96"></input>
Algeria
</label>
```

Comment: If you can get to the Label elements (`.document.getElementsByTagName("label")`) then you should be able to query each of the "selectit" ones using something like `.childNodes(0)` to get the `input` then `.childNodes(1)` should give you the text node with "Africa" , etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help @Tim Williams. I am not sure that worked on the elegance front but it has enabled me to move forward, I run into a bit of headache with the hierarchical nature of the list, and time as dictated a compromise of only supporting the first two levels of the hierarchy. It will do for now, but any further comments are certainly welcome!

**Localities**

```
    If artClassLocalities <> "" And Not IsNull(artClassLocalities) Then
        artClasses = Split(artClassLocalities, ",")
        Set Element = .Document.getElementByID("localitieschecklist")

        For i = 0 To Element.childNodes.Length - 1 'the element collection represents the globe


           'popular category items (6) one for each landmass
            Set Landmass = Element.childNodes(i)
           'landmass has 2 nodes
           'child 1 is the selectitnode node 0 (item 1)
            If InStr(1, artClassLocalities, Right(Landmass.childNodes(0).innerText, Len(Landmass.childNodes(0).innerText) - 1)) Then
                Call Landmass.childNodes(0).childNodes(0).setAttribute("checked", True)
            Else
                Call Landmass.childNodes(0).childNodes(0).setAttribute("checked", False)
            End If

            For j = 0 To Landmass.childNodes(1).childNodes.Length - 1 'the children are the countries
                Set Country = Landmass.childNodes(1).childNodes(j)    ' a given child is a country

                If InStr(1, artClassLocalities, Right(Country.childNodes(0).innerText, Len(Country.childNodes(0).innerText) - 1)) Then
                    Call Country.childNodes(0).childNodes(0).setAttribute("checked", True)
                Else
                    Call Country.childNodes(0).childNodes(0).setAttribute("checked", False)
                End If
               'Support for Subregions not yet functional
               'For k = 0 To Country.childNodes(1).childNodes.Length - 1
                'Set PAndADiv = Country.childNodes(j)

            Next
        Next
    End If
```